# How can I compare php extensions installed by version?

Tags: centos, php, centos7

I have PHP 7.1 and 7.3 installed on a Centos system. I ran into issues with my application when moving from 7.1 to 7.3 and suspect it's because I'm missing a required extension for 7.3. How can I easily compare the installed extensions for PHP 7.1 vs. 7.3 to identify what may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

As they are both still installed, you can compare the packages:

```
yum list installed | grep php
```